# How do I use ajax to auto refresh a section of page without manually invoking a function within javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var xmlhttp;

//Set up ajax first so he knows which guy to play with
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc)
{
    //Code to catch modern browsers
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    //Code to catch crap browsers
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    //Set up
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

//Set a function to deploy when something calls myFunction()
function myFunction()
{
    loadXMLDoc("../../../support/ajaxTest.txt",function()
    {
        //Fires off when button pressed
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("statusRefresh").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            setInterval( "alert('Hello I did something but i needed to be invoked by a button first')", 5000 );  
        }

    });
}
```

I want to call restful java service to refresh a 'status'. I need ajax to auto refresh the this status once the page has been hit. The Refresh method isnt instantaneous, for it has to talk with other machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function autoRefresh()
{
    var url    = "../../../support/ajaxTest.txt";
    var target = document.getElementById("statusRefresh");

    var doRefresh = function() 
    {
        loadXMLDoc(url, function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                target.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    });

    setInterval( doRefresh, 5000 );  
}
```

and

```
document.onload = autoRefresh;
```

Comment: so what will actually be firing off the autoRefresh? Just adding document.onload = autoRefresh; within the javascript scope will do this?

Answer (score 0):

more information is needed such as what is your goal, what do you currently have......what are you trying to do......If its a script thats triggered by something from example a user viewing your page or click a button then use that button to triiger the function to auto refresh

Another way is to use a crob job

Comment: If you're talking about "cronjob" (not "crob job" `=)`), it's not true. A cronjob is a server process, it doesn't influence the client (where the 'refresh' would take place).